# How to clear previous leaflet layer after click on new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, leaflet, react-leaflet

I try to remove selection of the layer when using a mouse click on new area.
[image: Selecting an area]

So there is on lick functionality on the layer

```
  layer.on({
    click: (event) => {
      event.target.setStyle({
        color: "black",
        weight: 1.5,
      });
    },
  });
```

And when I click on new area, I just get 2 areas with such border, but need only to select new one, and remove previous. Can anybody help with that?

[image]

Here is the code how I use geoJSON

```
<MapContainer center={getCenter()} zoom={getZoom()}>
    <GeoJSON
        ref={geoJSON}
        center={getCenter()}
        zoom={getZoom()}
        style={setColor}
        data={germanyDis}
        onEachFeature={onEachArea}
    />
</MapContainer>
```

And here is my `onEachArea` function

```
const onEachArea = (area, layer) => {
      layer.on({
        click: (event) => {
          event.target.setStyle({
            color: "black",
            weight: 1.5,
          });
          event.target.bringToFront();
   
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

So fixed this issues. Created a `usePrevious` hook to store previous target value and used it in `useEffect` hook

```
 const [selectedFeature, setSelectedFeature] = useState(null);
 const previousFeature = usePrevious(selectedFeature);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (previousFeature) {
      previousFeature.setStyle({ color: "transparent", weight: 0 });
    }
  }, [selectedFeature]);
```

And in onEachFeature function just set current value

```
const onEachArea = (area, layer) => {
      layer.on({
        click: (event) => {
          event.target.setStyle({
            color: "black",
            weight: 1.5,
          });
          event.target.bringToFront();

          setSelectedFeature(event.target);

        },
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add the layers via `L.geoJson` and with the `style` function, you can simply call on the geojson group `geojsonGroup.resetStyle()` in the click event:

```
layer.on({
    click: (event) => {
      geojsonGroup.resetStyle()
      event.target.setStyle({
        color: "black",
        weight: 1.5,
      });
    },
  });
```

Comment: Added a description of my geoJson above. I am using react-leaflet package.

Comment: Also tried this method, but for me it resets the whole map, but I need only previous area.